# To fight oneself?

Tags: expressions

If someone has the opportunity to do something that he would like to do but he knows that he shouldn't (for example sleeping with his best friend's wife), and he suffers from this moral dilemma, can I say "he is fighting himself"? Or "fighting with himself"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the word **conflict**.

**Conflict** can be used to mean *a mental struggle arising from opposing demands or impulses*

Using it in a sentence :

*I was conflicted; should I support the love of my life or be more pragmatic?*

Comment: Yes, conflicted is exactly what I mean, and yet it's not the word that I want to use. What about "to fight (with) oneself"? Is it idiomatic? Thanks!